# Save a database value in a session

Tags: java, servlets

I am quite new in java and servlets. I would like to know how to store a value retrieved from a database in a session variable so that i can use it for comparison and on other pages.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`HttpSession#setAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to store an object in the session along with a known attribute name.

```
SomeObject someObject = someDAO.find(someId);
request.getSession().setAttribute("someObject", someObject);
```

In subsequent requests in the same session, you can re-obtain it by [`HttpSession#getAttribute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) using the attribtue name.

```
SomeObject someObject = (SomeObject) request.getSession().getAttribute("someObject");
// ...
```

It's even accessible in JSP files by EL

```
${someObject}
```

which is useful if it's a fullworthy Javabean.

Comment: ...and make sure SomeObject is Serializable

Comment: This is indeed a good practice, but not a technical requirement.